# How can I find $P(X/Y \le t), P(XY \le t), P(XY/Z \le t)$?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, joint-distribution

In preparation for my final exam, I am trying to generate problems to solve. My professor suggested that I play with independent uniform distributions. So here are three probabilities that I have not been able to solve if $X,Y,Z \sim U(0,1)$ independently. (I also do not know if there is an "easy" answer to these.)

How can I find $P(X/Y \le t), P(XY \le t), P(XY/Z \le t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first two, draw an x-y plane with joint being nonzero over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Then, draw $X=tY$ and $XY=t$ respectively. Since $f(x,y)=1$ over the support, we're interested in the area of the portion of the unit square under the curves. Integration limits will depend on the value of $t$. For example, for $0<t<1$, $$P(XY\leq t)=1-\int_t^1\int_{t/x}^1dydx$$
You can find the distribution of $T=XY$ from $F_T(t)=P(XY\leq t)$ and use it in $P(T\leq tZ)$ similar to the first one you asked. Here, the joint will be different $f_{T,Z}(t,z)=f_T(t)f_Z(z)$.